# Correctly handle invalid query parameter in Servant

Tags: haskell, servant

I'm following along with [the Servant tutorial](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/tutorial/ApiType.html), and I've defined the following API type:

```hs
type UsersAPI = "users" :> QueryParam "sortby" SortBy :> Get '[JSON] [UserData]

data SortBy = Id | Name | Age

instance FromHttpApiData SortBy where
  parseQueryParam input =
    case toLower input of
      "name" -> Right Name
      "age"  -> Right Age
      _      -> Left $ append "Invalid sort order: " input

listUsers :: Maybe SortBy -> Handler [UserData]
listUsers = return . Db.getUsers . fromMaybe Id -- Db.getUsers just returns a a sorted in-memory list...

-- rest of implementation ommitted for brevity
```

Something is obviously correct, because if I `curl localhost:8081/users?sortby=name` or `curl localhost:8081/users?sortby=age` I get a correctly sorted list back. However, something is also broken, because `curl localhost:8081/users?sortby=foo` doesn't give me the expected `Invalid sort order: foo`. Instead, I get

> `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The full source is available here: https://github.com/tomasaschan/hello-servant

Comment: Having glanced at your code, my strong suspicion - although not certainty - is that the error comes from your use of `printf` in the `ToJSON` instance of `CalendarDate Gregorian`. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either of those libraries and the types seem "magical" enough that I cannot decode what your code is trying to do after merely briefly perusing the documentation.

Comment: Although of course that wouldn't explain why you get the expected result when you specify an allowed sort order, so perhaps that's not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to replicate the issue after cloning your repository. On inspection, the code all looks fine, aside from the dodgy `fromJust` calls.

Your repository also doesn't even build, by default - the `stack.yaml` file must be modified to include the `allow-newer: true` field. If you're using `cabal`, then it's impossible to know what versions of dependencies you're using, which will make troubleshooting this quite difficult.

Once this has been done, I get exactly the message you'd expect:

[image: the expected error output]

and all the sorting works just fine.

Can you post more details on your system? How are you building the project? What dependencies are in use?

Comment: This is interesting. At least it confirms that my understanding of how things should work is bot too far off. I'm gonna delete my .stack-work folder and try again...

Comment: OK, I found the error. It was completely unrelated to my Haskell code, but caused by how I looked at the response.

To make it easier to read, I piped the output of `curl` to `jq`, which shows the error message I see. In other words, you'll be able to reproduce with `curl localhost:8081/users?sortby=foo | jq`. Thanks for trying it out and convincing me that the Haskell code was correct!